# Как сделать подчёркивание целостным. Проблема с буквой "ц"

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать подчёркивание заголовка на приложенном изображении целостным, чтобы буква "ц" не нарушала линию.
Спасибо!
[image: Приложенное]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

text-decoration-skip-ink:none;

Comment: Спасибо! А как куда прописать этот код, чтобы он распространялся на весь сайт?

Comment: @QuickBrownFox к элементам к которым будете применяться свойство text-decoration, это свойство наследуется, применяется ко всем элементам.